# Javascript: Change <h2> headings color onmouseover()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement some native Javascript code so that when you mouse over a  heading the  heading will change color.

I will put all the JS code at the bottom with he HTML so you can see it in context but **the bit of code I've added to my .js file is as follows:**

```
//change <h2> on mouseover/mouseout
document.getElementsByClassName("heading2").onmouseover.style.color="red";
```

**The HTML document:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Session 5 - Dynamic Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="dynamicmenu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Web Programming Languages</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<p>
    JavaScript (JS) is an interpreted computer programming language. As part of web browsers, implementations allow client-side scripts to interact with the user, control the browser, communicate asynchronously, and alter the document content 
</p>

<h2>PHP</h2>
<p>
    PHP is a server-side scripting language designed for web development but also used as a general-purpose programming language. PHP is now installed on more than 244 million websites and 2.1 million web servers. Originally created by Rasmus Lerdorf in 1995, the 
</p>

<h2>Ruby</h2>
<p>
    Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language. It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan.Ruby embodies syntax inspired by Perl with Smalltalk-like features and was also influenced by Eiffel and Lisp. It supports multiple programming paradigms, includin
</p>

<h2>ASP</h2>
<p>
    Active Server Pages (ASP), also known as Classic ASP or ASP Classic, was Microsoft's first server-side script engine for dynamically generated web pages. Initially released as an add-on to Internet Information Services (IIS) via the Windows NT 4.0 Option Pack (ca. 1996), it was subsequently included as a free 
</p>

<h2>Java Server Pages</h2>
<p>
    Architecturally, JSP may be viewed as a high-level abstraction of Java servlets. JSPs are translated into servlets at runtime; each JSP's servlet is cached and re-used until the original JSP is modified.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Javascript Code:**

```
 //function to create dynamic menu...
    function dynamicMenu() {
        //Get all <h2> headings in to a container
        var headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

        //Create <div> for menu
        var menu = document.createElement("div");

        //Set id attribute for <div>
        menu.setAttribute("id", "navWrap")

        //Create <ul> for menu list items
        var menuUL = document.createElement("ul");

        //Set id attribute for <ul>
        menuUL.setAttribute("id", "mainNav");

        //Append the <ul> to the <div> as a child
        menu.appendChild(menuUL);

        //Set up loop to populate menu
        for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {

            //Collect the text content of h2 headings
            var linkText = headings[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            //Create <li> element
            var menuULitem = document.createElement("li");

            //Append <li> to <ul> as child
            menuUL.appendChild(menuULitem);

            //Create <a> tag element
            menuAtag = document.createElement("a");

            //Append <a> to <li> as child
            menuULitem.appendChild(menuAtag);

            //Set the <a> href attribute to point to the anchor tag in body of document
            menuAtag.setAttribute("href", "#item" + i)

            //Append link text as a hchild of <a>
            var menuText = document.createTextNode(linkText);
            menuAtag.appendChild(menuText);

            //Create an anchor point for each <h2>
            var anchor = document.createElement("a");

            //Set anchor attribute name
            anchor.setAttribute("name", "item" + i);

            //Insert anchor in to DOM
            document.body.insertBefore(anchor, headings[i]);

            //Give headings a class attribute
            headings[i].setAttribute("class", "heading2");

        }

        //Insert the Menu created in above loop in to the DOM
        document.body.insertBefore(menu, document.body.firstChild);

        //change <h2> on mouseover/mouseout
        document.getElementsByClassName("heading2").onmouseover.style.color="red";


    }//close function (dynamicMenu)

window.onload = dynamicMenu;
```

Comment: You can't just use CSS for this? `.heading2:hover {color:red;}`

Comment: I know I could use css, but I'm trying to find how to do it with javascript

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS

```
h2:hover
{
    color : red;
}
```

if you don't need to remove color when mouse moves out use

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

for (var i in headers)
{
    headers[i].onmouseover = function()
    {
        this.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with hover is that when you hover out the color changes back to what it was, but with onmouseover when you hover the text the text color changes and stays that way.

Comment: I know you can use css but I'm trying to do it with javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<h2 id="heading2" onmouseover="myFunction()">The Heading</h2>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("heading2").style.color = "red";
};
</script>
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
<h2 onmouseover="this.style.color = 'red'">The Heading</h2>
```

Comment: there is no function getElementByClassName, getElementsByClassName exists, so you need to access first element with [0]

Comment: you don't need to search element again using document.getElementById("heading2") just pass this variable to callback onmouseover="myFunction(this)"

Comment: meh inline event handlers

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use jquery. You can just do something like:`$("h2").hover(function() {
         $("h2").css(color:"red);
      });`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function with native javascript :

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("heading2");

// For each tag we add an event listener
for (var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    tags[i].onmouseover = mouseIn;
    tags[i].onmouseout = mouseOut;
}

function mouseIn (element) {
    element.target.style.color = "red";
}
function mouseOut (element) {
    element.target.style.color = "inherit";
}
```

Better (with jquery), add this at `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

So in the bottom of your page or other .js :

```
// Add event with event delegation 
// (does not care about add new .heading2 elements 
// and only an event is asigned to 'body' tag
$('body').on('mouseover', '.heading2' ,function(){ $(this).css({"color":"red"}); });
$('body').on('mouseout', '.heading2' ,function(){ $(this).css({"color":"inherit"}); });
```

... better and easiest! (simpliest css) :

In your .css style:

```
.heading2:hover {
    color: 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current syntax is not valid Javascript code.

What you are trying to achieve can be completed using one of the following Javascript syntactical options:

```
// Option 1: Event Listener
document.getElementsByClassName("heading2")[0].addEventListener("mouseover",
    function() { 
        this.style.color = "red";
    }, true);


// Option 2: Element Method
document.getElementsByClassName("heading2")[0].onmouseover = function() { 
    this.style.color = "red";
}; 


// Option 3: HTML Activation
<script>
    function setColor() { 
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
</script>

<h2 class="heading2" onmouseover="setColor()"></h2>
```

Of course you could also resort to the more simple CSS option:

```
h2.heading2:hover {
    color: red; 
}
```

... Or a Javascript library such as `JQuery`.